# How to display floating action button on bottom right corner - android

Tags: android

I am using this layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityStartShopping">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomButtons"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cart"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For me Floating action button is displaying in top left corner.

How to display it bottom right corner.

Comment: Try adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:gravity="bottom|end"` in `fab` ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I made changes according to your suggestion. Now its displaying bottom left. How to display it bottom right.

Comment: Add `bottom|right` instead of `end` .

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:elevation="6dp" />
```

It's better to use CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

Change your root ***RelativeLayout*** to ***android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout***

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the `dependencies` for design which is like this, this will be added under the `dependencies` block of the `app` module of the `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

[image]

without this you will not be able to use `CoordinatorLayout`, `FloatingActionButton`

I have changed few resource as i don't have resource which you have showed in your question.

> layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ActivityStartShopping">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_contact_card" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this should look like this

[image: output]